# How to FadeOut / FadeIn content with ReactJS at onClick event?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, css-animations

This is my code so far and [here is a working fiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/elvismdev/jp20ey2g/).

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var FooterMenu = React.createClass({
  onClick: function (type) {
    var content;

    switch (type) {
      case 'A':
      content = <p>Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Nulla sit amet est. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Praesent egestas tristique nibh. Morbi nec metus.
                Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Pellentesque posuere. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. In turpis. Donec posuere vulputate arcu.                                 Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Maecenas malesuada. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et                                       ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>;
      break;
      case 'B':
          content = <p>Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nunc sed turpis. Duis leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi                                       tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam cursus lacinia erat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut,                                           mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nunc nulla. Donec mollis                                            hendrerit risus. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. In dui magna, posuere                                       eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula. Vivamus euismod mauris.</p>;
      break;
      default:
      throw new Error('Unimplemented type');
    }
    this.props.setActiveContent(content);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <ul className="text-muted list-inline main-menu">
                <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'A')}>Menu Item A</li>
                <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'B')}>Menu Item B</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
      );
  }
});
var MainContent = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    activeContent: React.PropTypes.any
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{this.context.activeContent}</div>
      </div>
      );
  }
});
var MainContentWrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300} >
        <MainContent />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
});
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      activeContent: <h1>Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl</h1>
    }
  },
  childContextTypes: {
    activeContent: React.PropTypes.any
  },
  getChildContext: function () {
    return {
      activeContent: this.state.activeContent
    };
  },
  setActiveContent: function (content) {
    this.setState({activeContent: content});
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.replaceState(this.getInitialState());
    }.bind(this),60000);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainContentWrapper />
        <FooterMenu setActiveContent={this.setActiveContent} />
      </div>
      );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

All I want to do is to create a FadeOut/FadeIn transition animation to hide and show the selected content to display. When clicked on **Menu Item A** or **Menu Item B**, then *FadeOut* the active text displaying above the menu and *FadeIn* with the new content.

How can I accomplish this? *I'm new to ReactJS*

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question but here is an live example - https://jsfiddle.net/n5Luz6ym/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a really good example but it does what you need (https://jsfiddle.net/jp20ey2g/7/).

And you [**should not**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#when-not-to-use-context) use `context` as global variable - i've cleaned up that part in favor to `props`.

```
var FooterMenu = React.createClass({
  onClick: function (type) {
    var content;

    switch (type) {
      case 'A':
      content = <p>Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Nulla sit amet est. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Praesent egestas tristique nibh. Morbi nec metus.
                Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Pellentesque posuere. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. In turpis. Donec posuere vulputate arcu.                                 Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Maecenas malesuada. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et                                       ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>;
      break;
      case 'B':
          content = <p>Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nunc sed turpis. Duis leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi                                       tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam cursus lacinia erat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut,                                           mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nunc nulla. Donec mollis                                            hendrerit risus. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. In dui magna, posuere                                       eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula. Vivamus euismod mauris.</p>;
      break;
      default:
      throw new Error('Unimplemented type');
    }
    this.props.setActiveContent(content);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <ul className="text-muted list-inline main-menu">
                <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'A')}>Menu Item A</li>
                <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'B')}>Menu Item B</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
      );
  }
});
var MainContent = React.createClass({
  componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
    if (this.props.content !== nextProps.content) {
        this.setState({ opacity: 0 })
    }
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { opacity: 1 }
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function () {
    if (this.state.opacity !== 1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ opacity: 1 })
      }, 200)
    }
  },
  render: function () {
    var style = {
        opacity: this.state.opacity,
      transition: this.state.opacity > 0 ? 'opacity 0.2s ease-in' : 'none'
    }
    console.log(this.state.opacity)
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row" style={style}>
            {this.props.content}
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      activeContent: <h1>Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl</h1>
    }
  },
  childContextTypes: {
    activeContent: React.PropTypes.any
  },
  getChildContext: function () {
    return {
      activeContent: this.state.activeContent
    };
  },
  setActiveContent: function (content) {
    this.setState({activeContent: content});
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.replaceState(this.getInitialState());
    }.bind(this),60000);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainContent content={this.state.activeContent} />
        <FooterMenu setActiveContent={this.setActiveContent} />
      </div>
      );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try and report back w/ questions - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html. It's fairly straight-forward, but took a bit of playing for me to get right.

Comment: I have been trying to implement it like in that example from the documentation, but seems like I'm missing some part or implementing it wrong for my particular case. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/elvismdev/jp20ey2g/6/